# Highcharts : smooth / anti-aliasing line

Tags: highcharts, antialiasing

I use a basic line chart from highcharts library and I think that the lines are not smooth enough.

It's possible to improve it ?

My code :

```
    chart: {
            type:'line',
            renderTo: 'issues_by_release',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
            },
    yAxis: { 
            min:0,
            labels:{ enabled:true },
            title: {
                     text:'Issues'
                   }                          
           },
    xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',    
            tickLength:10,  
            categories:['1','2','3','4','5'],
            labels:{ rotation:-45, 
                     align:'right'
                   }                           
            },
    plotOptions: {
                    line: {                            
                            dataLabels: {
                                            enabled: true                                                    
                                        },
                            enableMouseTracking : false,
                            showInLegend: true
                        }                        
                    },                                
                    series: [{
                            type: 'line',                           
                            name: 'Testers', 
                            data: [1,2,3,4,5]                                                           
                            }                           
                            ]
            });
        });
```

Thank you  in advance !

Comment: Highcharts offers a spline fit:  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/grid

Answer (score 7):

I've solved adding the line

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.getPointSpline = Highcharts.seriesTypes.spline.prototype.getPointSpline;
```

before creating the chart (adapted from [this](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37736) thread).

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t1phfvmL/) on JSFiddle. Screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It depends on whether what you want is actually improved antialiasing, or if what you really want is a smoother curve interpolated through the data points.

If you want better antialiasing, you'd have to look at the SVG options - though I don't see much room for improvement in this case, honestly.

If you want a smooth curve then what you want is the spline chart type:

http://highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands

Just keep in mind that a spline distorts the data by using a particular formula to smooth a curve between points, which can increase the severity of the difference between high and low points - it shouldn't be used simply for aesthetics.